# Checking a superclass of a related model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an AuthUser model which I use a `get_profile()` call to get some info about the user (Ignore the fact that profiles are deprecated - I'm not really using them as profiles). However, there are two different profile models (`Student`, and `StaffMember`) both subclassing an abstract model (`SchoolPerson`). The following code worked in django 1.6, but no longer works on django 1.8:

```
def get_profile(self):
    for related in self._meta.get_all_related_objects():
        if related.model.__base__.__name__ == 'SchoolPerson':  # TODO - might we have non-SchoolPerson profiles?
            try:
                return getattr(self, related.get_accessor_name())
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
    raise ObjectDoesNotExist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it not work? What is the traceback? The _meta API has been normalized in django 1.8

Answer (score 1):

According to the Django 1.8 documentation the `get_all_related_objects()` method has been deprecated although that implies it should still work for the time being.. that being said you could try updating all the deprecated methods found from the examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#migrating-old-meta-api)

For the `get_all_related_objects()` given the example (copied and pasted)

```
MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()


[
    f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
    if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one) and f.auto_created
]
```

this is just a suggestion. Let me know how you get on :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers; this is what I ended up using. Still haven't worked out why it failed in the first place though :-/

```
def get_profile(self):
    for field in self._meta.get_fields():
        if field.one_to_one and 'SchoolPerson' in [base.__name__ for base in field.related_model.__bases__]:
            try:
                return getattr(self, field.get_accessor_name())
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
    raise ObjectDoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Migrating from the old API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api) section of the docs. It has examples. Consider substituting of `MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()` with

```
[
    f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
    if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one) and f.auto_created
]
```